# Initializer element code error

Tags: c

When I run this piece of code:

```
void main(){
   int a = 5;
   static int i = a+5;
   printf("%d", i);
}
```

I get the error: **initializer element is not constant**

What does this mean?

Comment: Note: `void main` makes baby Jesus cry.

Comment: @cHao void main has nothing to do with this problem...

Comment: @AMIT: That's why i didn't post it as an answer.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static variables in function scope go in data segment. Data segment is initialized at compile time. That means the initial value has to be known at compile time. In your case, the initial value (value of a) comes from a variable on stack which is available only at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In C Initializer should be some constant. however you can do something like this...

```
int a = 5;
static int i;
i = a + 5;
printf("%d", i);
```

this will not generate any error...

Comment: what you are saying is intitializer should be constant but what about this code    void main()
    {
    int a=5;

    int i=a+5;

    printf("%d",i);

    }

Comment: static variable should be initialized with constant not with expression which include variables. please correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a variable to a static.

Answer (score 0):

since you initialize the variable `i` not with a constant number (like `int a = 5;`) but with an expression (`a+5`) which is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static` mean that there will be exactly one instance of the variable `i`, and that instance will live throughout the life of the program. This is useful, for example, if you want to store values between function calls.

As the variable is initialized when the application is started, the value must be constant.

In your case, there is no need to declare the "static", as it will get a new value every time the function is called.